# How can I delete a tweet using Twitter web interface?

Tags: twitter

How can I delete a specific tweet? The delete icon on Twitter has disappeared from the web app interface. It used to be on the same line as the Repy and Favorite actions.

Can I restore the icon somehow, or is there another way to delete a tweet?

Answer (score 4):

[Quoting @Support](https://twitter.com/Support/status/505040699171930112) (Twitter's official support account) from yesterday,

> The "Delete Tweet" button is now in the “••• More” menu on http://Twitter.com .

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like for me:

[image: screenshot of 'more' menu]